# I don't understand what the * in "$x*" in my Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Here's some code for some context.

```
for x in {a..z};
do
    for y in $x*;do
        if  [ "$y" != "$x*" ]; then
        let "count++"
```

If someone can try to explain what that 2nd for loop does I would appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a really inefficient and ugly way of counting how many files in the current directory start with the letters a through z. The outer loop executes once for each letter, and for each one, the inner loop executes once for each file starting with that letter - `$x*` expands to `a*` through `z*` and then to files matching that pattern (Or just the pattern if none do, assuming `nullglob` is off. The `if` catches those cases though it has issues if the filename is literally `a*` etc.).

A better way to count the number of files matching a pattern in `bash` is to store all the filenames in an array using a single more efficient glob pattern, and then get the array's length:

```sh
shopt -s nullglob
files=([a-z]*)
count=${#files[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default (`shopt -u nullglob`), for the glob pattern `foo*`, if there are no files matching it, the pattern will expand to the literal string `foo*`. See the following example which you can try.

```
$ cat ../foo.sh
count=0
for x in {a..z}; do
    for y in $x*; do
        if  [ "$y" != "$x*" ]; then
            let "count++"
        fi
    done
done
echo $count
$ ls
a1 a2 b3 c4 z5
$ bash ../foo.sh
5
$ x=a
$ for file in $x*; do echo "$file"; done
a1
a2
$ x=b
$ for file in $x*; do echo "$file"; done
b3
$ x=f
$ for file in $x*; do echo "$file"; done
f*
$
```

Search for `nullglob` in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html) for more details.

As others pointed out the code is not *technically* correct unless you are sure there are no filenames including a literal `*` char. Or you can change `[ "$y" != "$x*" ]` to `[ -e "$y" ]`.

```
$ ls -1
a1
a2
b3
c4
z5
z6*
$ cat ../foo.sh
count=0
for x in {a..z}; do
    for y in $x*; do
        if  [ -e "$y" ]; then
        #   ^^^^^^^^^^^
            let "count++"
        fi
    done
done
echo $count
$ bash ../foo.sh
6
$
```